# Ti c66x multiply intrinsics for 64bit output

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, texas-instruments

I am trying to do 32x32 multiplication by using DSP c66x intrinsics .

I am having values like this

```
int32_t beta[4] ={185931936,84529224,-144944792,-175891288};
int32_t alfa[4] ={28505,24851,11653,13268};
```

CPP code:

```
    int64_t mult =0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
     mult += beta[i] * alfa[i];
    }
```

C66x CODE:

```
__x128_t _qmpy32 (__x128_t src1, __x128_t src2);
```

I am planning to use above instruction ,But the problem is i did not find any instruction which will give me result in 2x64 bit instead of 4x32 bit .and because of above instruction I am getting wrong result .Can any one tell me is there any other instruction available DSP c66x to multiply two 32 bit values and get the result in 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is _mpy32ll. Try this:

```
mult += _mpy32ll(beta[i], alfa[i]);
```

Comment: Then i can not do the 4 data's multiplication at a time :(.I have to follow C type of loop to do the multiplication .

Comment: There is no instruction to do more than one 32x32 multiply with 64 bit result in a single cycle. However, the CPU has 2 of these multipliers, the A side and B side, so two of the multiplies can be done simultaneously. Sorry, but that's all the CPU can do.